# Pushing cycles out of singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $X$ be a smooth complex quasi-projective variety and $Y$ a projective complex variety. Let's assume $Z$ is the singular locus of $Y$. We assume that $\text{codim}_Y(Z)\gg \text{dim}(X)$. Let's assume that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism such that $f^{-1}(Z)$ is codimension $1$ subvariety of $X$. Is it possible to find a sequence of morphisms $f_{\alpha}: X\rightarrow Y$ such that for each $\alpha$, $f_{\alpha}^{-1}(Z)$ is either empty or a codimension $\geq 2$ subvariety of $X$ such that $f_{\alpha}$ converges to $f$ in compact open topology induced from the analytic topology and the furthermore the graphs of $f_{\alpha}$ in $\overline{X}\times Y$ have bounded degree? ($\overline{X}$ is some projective closure of $X$.)

Looking at the cycle on $\overline{X}\times Y$ corresponding to the closure of graph of the morphism $f$, then using the Moving lemma due to Friedlander and Lawson [Theorem 3.1](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1163/docs/Preprint_versionsPublications/9/mvlmj.pdf), one can show that there is a sequence of irreducible cycles on the Chow variety of $\overline{X}\times Y$ that converge to the cycle corresponding to $f$ and these intersect $\overline{X}\times Z$ in codimension $\geq 2$. Now the question is, is it possible somehow to choose these cycles in a way that they correspond to the closure of a graph of a morphism from $X$ to $Y$?